# Extract tag attributes from HTML with regex

Tags: php, regex

I want to read all tag attributes with the word title, HTML sample below

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div title="abc"> </div>
        <div> 
            <span title="abcd"> </span>
        </div>
        <input type="text" title="abcde">
    </body>
</html>
```

I have tried this regex function, which doesn't work

```
preg_match('\btitle="\S*?"\b', $html, $matches);
```

Comment: You would be better off using DOMDocument rather than try and hack it with regexs.

Comment: /title="(.*)"/g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to follow up on my comment, using regex's isn't particularly safe or robust enough to manage HTML (although with some HTML - there is little hope of anything working fully) - have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1213708.

Using DOMDocument provides a more reliable method, to do the processing you are after you can use XPath and search for any `title` attributes using `//@title` (the `@` sign is the XPath notation for attribute).

```
$html = '<html>
<head>
   <title> </title>
</head>
 <body>
   <div title="abc"> </div>
   <div> 
           <span title="abcd"> </span>
   </div>
       <input type="text" title="abcde">
</body>
</html>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

foreach($xpath->query('//@title') as $link) {
    echo $link->textContent.PHP_EOL;
}
```

which outputs...

```
abc
abcd
abcde
```

Comment: thank you , it worked perfect, i have accepted this as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a regex solution

```
preg_match_all('~\s+title\s*=\s*["\'](?P<title>[^"]*?)["\']~', $html, $matches);
$matches = array_pop($matches);
foreach($matches as $m){
    echo $m . " ";
}
```